# How to get a remainder in java

Tags: java

The Student Union is organising a student trip and they are determining how many cars are required.
Prompt the user to enter the total number of students going on the trip.
Then determine how many cars are required (5 to a car) and how many students are left without transport.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class P2Trip
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int students;
    int space = 5;
    int sum;

    System.out.println("How many students are going today?: ");
    students = input.nextInt();

    sum =(students / space);
    System.out.println("Ammount of cars needed: " + sum);

 }
}//code works fine, but im not sure how to get a remainder of students without a lift.
```

Comment: Try to do your homework by your own. you won't ever understand if you ask help everytime without trying

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a homework dump.

Comment: I wish that were an actual option for flagging.

Comment: @robbmj Just use the `low quality` flag. That means the same.

Comment: Relax people just needed some help no need to get so offensive... people these days, its not like I harmed you in any way.

Comment: @Mike: no, you were harming yourself by asking your question the way you initially asked it.

Comment: And how did I do this Sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like you just need help with who will be left without a car. You need to use modular division (some people call it remainder) with the percent sign (%). Here is the line of code you  are missing:

```
System.out.println("Amount of people without a car: "+students%sum);
```

The full code for the program is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) [
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int carCapacity=5;

        System.out.println("How many students?");
        int students=s.nextInt();
        int cars=students/carCapacity;
        int leftOver=students%carCapacity;

        System.out.println("Cars needed: "+cars);
        System.out.println("Students left over: "+leftOver);


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude this seemed to work fine. I was checking over my lab notes but could not really find any content that could help me. Thanks.

Comment: In stack overflow, we thank people by accepting their answers (hint hint). No problem though :).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the remainder/modulo operator here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there are two corrections you can do in your program:

```
sum = (student/space);
int leftstudent;`
leftstudent=(students%space);
System.out.println("left students without transport are " +leftstudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the modular division operator in Java.

Division / Divisor =  **coefficient**

Division % Divisor = **remainder**

To find the remainder of number students for example you will have to use "%".